# jQuery Ajax callback is either not triggered or not working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I just started experimenting with jQuery and ajax. I have looked through similar posts but I am still unable to resolve my issue.

So here goes, I am writing a wordpress plugin. I have the following:

```
 add_action('wp', 'wl_init');

 add_action('wp_ajax_wl_add_wishlist', 'wl_wishlist_process');
 add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_wl_add_wishlist', 'wl_wishlist_process');

 function wl_wishlist_process (){
    echo 'test';
    die();
 }

  function wl_init(){
      wp_register_script( 'wishlist-js', plugins_url( '/wishlist.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery') );

      wp_localize_script( 'wishlist-js', 'myAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));

      wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery');
      wp_enqueue_script( 'wishlist-js' );
  }
```

And this is my js file"

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('#wl_wishlist').click(function(e) {
            alert('This runs');
            //var plugurl = document.location.protocol+'//'+document.location.host+'/test/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';
            //"<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>"
            //"/test/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"
            jQuery.ajax({url: myAjax.ajaxurl, type: 'post', data: {action: 'wl_wishlist_process', post_id:100}, success: function(response) {
                alert(response);
            },
            error : function (xhr){
                alert('There is an error');

            }});

        });
});
```

I know the js file is loaded and running as I see the alert('This runs'). However, it neither gives me success nor error. Is it error with the ajax call or is it the callback function error? What am I missing here?

Also, When I open the url of the ajax call (http://localhost/test/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php), it shows '0'. Is this correct?

I have used all the commented methods to get the url, but none works.

Thanks!

Comment: A `0` response from the wordpress ajax endpoint indicates that either no action or an invalid action was passed in. Your action should be `wl_add_wishlist` rather than `wl_wishlist_process`. That will fix your hard-coded ajax url. Does wordpress know that it is in a subdirectory (`/test/`)? That would explain why the localized URL isn't working.

Comment: Ah that's the issue! I changed it to `wl_add_wishlist` and it is now working. If i add `wp_localize_script( 'benwishlist-js', 'myAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));` does it solve the issue of hardcoding the url? Do you mind elaborating how would wordpress know it is in the subdirectory? Many thanks!